# How do you write a property so that you can access inner variables?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, properties

I have a property enclosing a rectangle I have called it Window.
when I try to use the property to change the location or "X" value of the rectangle, I get an error: "Can not modify the return value of Window because it is not a variable."

Now I know I can just directly access the variable, but I would prefer to be able just modify the "X" value. I also don't want to be creating a new rectangle every time I modify it.

So is there something I can add to my property that will let me modify the X value through the property?

This is where I am trying to use the property:

```
Window.X -= amount;
```

This is where I have the proprty:

```
private Rectangle _window;
public Rectangle Window
{
    get { return _window;}
    set
    {
        if (/*condition*/)
            _window = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is that `Rectangle` is `struct`. Property accessor is actually a method and when it returns struct it is just copied, so you can't modify underlying struct that way.

Solutions:

1. If Rectangle is your code make it class.
2. `r = Window; r.X -= amount; Window = r;`

By the way you should thank C# compiler for that, becase technically it can modify that X, but it would be field/prop of temporary object, it would make later debugging a hell for you. In C++ it actually compiles.

Also it is good example why structures should be immutable. You just wouldn't have that temptation.

Comment: thanks It would be nice if the compile could just implicitly do these steps could treat it like an immutable object so it would work like strings

Answer (score 1):

`Rectangle` is a `struct` - hence your property returns a **value**, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `System.Drawing.Rectangle` is be defined as a struct (value type).

It's not allowed because when you reference the property you get a copy of the value (struct). Assigning the X property on the struct therefore has impact on the Window property.